# Why localhost is not working from Windows 11 to WSL2

Tags: networking, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Postgresql 14 on WSL2 & Datagrip in windows. After connecting postgresql databases from WSL2 to Datagrip it works fine, but after a few seconds or minutes it says refure to connect:

[image]

> I think somehow the IP or something is blocking by WSL2 or maybe
> windows 11 has problem with wsl2 again

**SYSTEM:**

```
WSL     : 2
Windows : 11
Disto   : Ubuntu-22.04
```

Comment: I'm 90% confident that those are two separate problems.  Would you consider posting "Problem 2" as a separate question?  The new question would be about "Why localhost is not working from Windows 11 to WSL2".  I can provide likely provide answers to both, but they are definitely two different answers to the two different questions.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks, Can you help me now? (I did problem 2 cause I was 99% confident it was not postgresql but the whole network connection problem between WSL2 & Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite - You are probably correct and they may be the same problem.  The way the title was written, I thought the first problem was about connecting from WSL2 to Windows, and the second was about connecting from Windows to WSL2.  But it sounds like *both* are about connecting from Windows to WSL2 - Is this right?  Don't worry about editing the question again (for now) - But do try running `wsl --shutdown` (from PowerShell) and try again.  You may be running into a common bug, so let's rule that out as a possibility first.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. 

I tried `wsl --shutdown` restarting windows again, installing a new distro to check if work (not a smart work but just to make sure it works or not) At this point it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Ok, let's try a super-simple test.  It *should* fail, since your React test failed, but simply run `python3 -m http.server 3001`.  Can you access http://localhost:3001 in Chrome in Windows?  Again, I'm expecting it to fail, but that should then tell us what type of problem we're looking at.  Not sure if I can *solve* it, but at least I can provide some possibilities at that point.  Thanks!

Comment: And if it does fail, does it work if you use the network address in Chrome instead of localhost?  You can find this address with `ip addr show eth0`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry, But it was argent for me to work on a project. ( I am using WSL, WSL2 from like 3+ years with 1000 of hussles. I just give up on it with those *** network issues, I yesterday I was uninstalled it) But just installed to know the problem when you replied. just give me a few minutes. Thank you so much for your valuable time. just give me 1 minute more please. I just want to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138838/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-tahazzot).

Comment: 0


I am having this same issue. it is for anything I host on WSL2. IT works for a few seconds/minutes then refuses to connect from windows -> wsl. I can still connect from the same and other wsl distros. Just not from windows. It has worked fine for over a year then it started doing this.

Comment: @Ben I'm worried that you may have lost your ability to comment here (or join chat) when you put 100 rep on the question.  It might have been better to do 50 rep so that you would still had enough left to communicate.  If you can't reply here, could I suggest that you also open a separate question with any additional details that you can provide so that we can ask questions about your situation?  Thanks!

Comment: @Ben I've provided an answer, and I'm kind of assuming that either the issue has (hopefully) now resolved for you or will resolve with a `wsl --update` based on the fix.  Again, I know that you likely lost the ability to comment when you put most of your 101 rep to the 100 point bounty :-/.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*This is not an answer for the *original problem*, but there was a bounty added on this question on January 26th, 2023 that is likely a different root issue, but with the same symptoms as the original question.  This answer, I believe, will address the *new* issue (but ironically, 1 hour too late for the bounty).*</sub>

This sounds like a bug in the 1.1.0 pre-release of WSL that was reported in issue ([#9508](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9508)).  The timing of the appearance of this issue for the bounty-poster would roughly coincide with this release.

The issue is reported to be *mostly* fixed in a new pre-release yesterday, ([1.1.2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/1.1.2)).

Comment: WSL2 is good not the best option for many reasons even though they are using the kernel! I had a lot issues with network & slow file system . According to their recommendations creating file inside the Linux file system has massive performance improvement. But I don't know how my network & other problems fixed. (Maybe for the update or switching to other distro)